# Image and video gallery on drupal website

Tags: drupal-6

I want to implement video and image gallery for every user in drupal website.
I am using drupal 6, and requirement is any user can create Image or video to their own gallery after loged in.

How can i go to this. Please give me Idea  or link where step by step process is given. If any module is there ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and it's [Image Field](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) and [Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield) to create content types for image entries and video entries.

You can then use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create a paginated, filterable list of nodes restricted to only image or video content types that were created by the current user.